# How to install wireless USB adapter

Tags: wireless

I have Xubuntu 16.04 and wish to add a TP-Link Archer T1U USB adapter. I tried following manufacturer's instructions bit I'm totally lost. Then, I tried following instructions in Ubuntu and other Forums, but again I'm totally lost.

My Wireless card is TP-Link Archer T1U. Laptop is Toshiba Satellite T135-1309.

Comment: Have you tried just plugin and wait for the drivers to load?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your wireless adaptor and give it a moment to detect the hardware, then check the network icon on the taskbar to see if it has worked.  Failing that run the Software Sources and click on Additional Drivers to auto-detect any new drivers available for your hardware (you need to be connected to internet via lan cable for this to work).